# addChangeListener not working Realm Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I am using Realm DB in my android app. Data is being saved/updated successfully but the problem is that addChangeListener is not being called when I add/update data.
This is my Code (Kotlin):

**In MainActivity:**

```
        Realm.init(this)
        // Get a Realm instance for this thread
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("coinbundle.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
                .build()
        val realm = Realm.getInstance(config)

        val  bundles = realm.where(BundleDB::class.java).findAll()
        bundles.addChangeListener(RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<BundleDB>> {
            Log.d("myanswer","lisnter worked")
        })
```

**In BackgroundService I am saving data like this:**

```
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("coinbundle.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
                .build()
        val realm = Realm.getInstance(config)
        realm.beginTransaction()
        BundleObj = realm.createObject(BundleDB::class.java, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        BundleObj!!.name = "MY_BUNDLE_NAME"
        realm.commitTransaction()
```

Comment: see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications

Comment: By declaring `RealmResults` variable outside of `onCreate` worked for me!